# Changing 2 images at mousePressed

Tags: java, arrays, image, mouseevent, slick2d

I have 2 images of legs of a character, I want them to be changing while I pressed the keyboard for example left or right arrow key. It's like the character is walking. How to do this in java slick2d? I have no codes to provide because I have no Idea how to start coding it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to handle basic input and you don't need to use slick2D then you can just use a KeyListener or MouseListener for input. These are Java features and are very simple to use.

To use Slick2D, my best guess would be to start here,
[Slick Commands](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/)

These are for more advanced inputs I believe but you should do some research on each to see what you need to use.